# Python cannot append data in JSON file

Tags: python

I'm trying to make Discord bot that users can save their own custom chat triggers,
but I have a problem while saving chat triggers

when i type `!learn test1` pass and `!learn test2 pass`, there's only one trigger saved in JSON.

```json
{
    "wordlist": {
        "word": "test1",
        "response": "('pass',)",
        "owner": "b4psa3"
    }
}
```

and my code is:

```py
@client.command()
async def learn(ctx, wordreceived, *wordresponse):
    try:
        with open("wordlist.p", "rb") as file:
            what_word_received = pickle.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        with open("wordlist.p", "wb") as file:
            what_word_received = list()
            pickle.dump(what_word_received, file)
    
    if wordreceived not in what_word_received:
        what_word_received.append(wordreceived)
        with open("wordlist.p", "wb") as file:
            pickle.dump(what_word_received, file)
        file_path = "./words.json"
        if os.path.isfile(file_path) == True:
            with open(file_path, "r", encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                data = json.load(outfile)

            data['wordlist'].append({
                    "word": f"{wordreceived}",
                    "response": f"{wordresponse}",
                    "owner": f"{ctx.message.author.name}"
                })
                
            with open(file_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                json.dump(data, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
        else:
            data = {}
            data['wordlist'] = []
            data['wordlist'] = {
                    "word": f"{wordreceived}",
                    "response": f"{wordresponse}",
                    "owner": f"{ctx.message.author.name}"
                }
            with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
                json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)
    else:
        print(what_word_received)
        await ctx.send("This word is already exist")
```

Comment: And what code is executed and with which paramers? And what does it do when you run that code in isolation?

Comment: Your `wordlist` value is a dict, not a list - it's not something that you can append to.  You probably want it to be list of dicts.

Comment: you may have to read all data from file, add new data, and write all data back to file,

Comment: I want to make a Discord bot function that save someone's word trigger and reply with saved respond when user type saved trigger. And i'm making sace function in list and JSON. List is for check if word registered, and JSON file is for save word and trigger's owner.

Comment: Sorry for my bad english and explaination. I want to add new date in data['wordlist'] as dict. According to a post i read data['wordlist'].append() should be work, but in my case, it doesn't work.